# Extract some information using a WMI query and send it to file

Tags: powershell

I'm collecting information using a WMI query. I want to send this information to a CSV file including the machine name. I can send the information but I'm not able to include machine name with it.

```
$PasswordState = Get-WmiObject -Class Lenovo_BiosPasswordSettings -Namespace root\wmi |
    Select -Expand PasswordState |
    Select-Object -Last 1 |
    Out-File -FilePath '\\server\share\Bios_Password_Status.csv' -Append -Encoding Unicode
```

I need this to create a CSV file with two items:

1. Data returned from WMI query
2. Machine name

Comment: The machine name is automatically included in WMI responses. Replace `Out-File` with `Export-Csv` and perhaps select the exact fields you want exported, and the code will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this give you what you want, it will store the result in an array called $Output. You can then use $Output | Out-File -Append to add it to a file or something.

```
$Result = Get-WmiObject -Class Lenovo_BiosPasswordSettings -Namespace root\wmi | Select -Property PSComputerName,PasswordState
$Output += $Result | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
```